# SSAS Tabular Model - Multiple Fact tables

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, ssas, data-analysis, ssas-tabular

I have a model with three fact tables and three dimensions. Each fact table can individually relate to each dimension, this works fine. But the three dimensions are in this schema not related and therefore cannot be used with each other by the client.

I have tried many solutions, one of them was merging the DimPerson, DimDepartment and DimDistrict by Crossjoin to get "all possible combinations". But given the number of rows in each of these dimensions, the task takes too long.

Any ideas? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Here is the schema:

[image: Diagram]

Comment: You cannot relate fact tables to each other via dimtables, but since they share the same dimension you wil be able to compare them though the same dimension attributes.

Comment: Otherwise this stairway: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/steps/stairway-to-ssas-tabular-level-8-multiple-fact-tables-and-perspectives

Comment: Thanks @SqlKindaGuy, I have read the article but kind of reluctant to introduce Perspective.. What do you mean by comparing throught the same dimention attributes? Looks like there was something wrong with the picture I uploaded, should work now.

Comment: you have to make it both-directional. You cannot reference fact to fact. You can relate fact to dim to fact. And then they are combined through the shared attribute values

Comment: Hi. Im little bit confused about your objective. These dimension tables obviously derived from the transaction tables. And the sole purpose of creating the dimension tables are to  separately slice the fact tables. Can you please explain why you need to combine these dimention tables?

Answer (score 1):

We have lots of models like this. The most common shared dimension is Date. We filter Date on every dashboard using the dimension and all the Fact tables return the filtered values. Be sure to use the Dimension columns for filtering, not the Fact table columns. Best practice is to hide the Fact columns (PersonID, DeptID, DistrictID) so these columns are only available via the Dimensions.